# Using KIVY Popup I have NameError

Tags: python, kivy

Last time I solved the error thanks to you.
However, due to my lack of skills, 
I looked up a lot of data but couldn't solve the error.

1. If I click information Button happen this error message.
   File "", line 27, in 
   NameError: name 'Factory' is not defined
2. I want to make Project. This Picture. But The Button location always not good.
   [image]
   This is My Python KIVY code

```
#project.kv file

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'
Upper_bar:
size_hint: (1, 0.1)
Label:
text: 'Select Mode'
BoxLayout:
padding: [90, 40]
size_hint: (1, 0.5)
orientation: 'horizontal'
Button:
        size_hint: (0.5, 1)
        text: 'Object'

    BoxLayout:

    Button:
        size_hint: (0.5, 1)
        text: 'Street'

<Upper_bar>:
BoxLayout:
Button:
    size_hint: (0.3, 1)
    text: 'Information'
    on_press: Factory.InformationPop().open()

<InformationPop@Popup>:
size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
tittle: 'Information'
auto_dismiss: True
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text:
            """Name:
            Student Number:
            E-mail: """

    Button:
        text:
            'Close'
        on_press:
            root.dismiss()
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '40dp'
'''

class Upper_bar(BoxLayout):
    pass

class AIObjectCameraApp(App): 

def build(self): 
    return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    AIObjectCameraApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to add the import of `Factory` at the top of your `kv` string:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
```